# How can i manipulate values of each region in a mask that has multiple regions in fastest way?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

So, i'm working on some processing step of a segmentation model for text localization.

So for simplified questions. I've made a few images below:

1. **The mask** (The values of each region is marked "1" and other cell in grey is "0" as default) (1)

[image]

So, i want to do something to get to this tensor where each region now has the value of summing all values of it. The target tensor is image below (2)

2. **The target**

[image]

**Question**: Is there a method that do what i need in matrix-style (for faster compute) or some related keywords for tasks like this ?

**What i tried**: I have tried using the label coordinates to loop with OpenCV's **findContours()** but i don't know that is the best practice for this kind of manipulating task.

**For array reproduction**:

```py
import numpy as np
mask = np.array([[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                     [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0],
                     [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
                     [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0],
                     [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                     [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]], dtype=np.float32)
```

(Edit: add numpy array for reproducible)

Comment: please provide your input in a reproducible format (code to generate the numpy array)

Comment: @mozway I added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`scipy.ndimage.label`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.label.html) to identify the clusters, then compute the sum per group:

```
from scipy import ndimage

labels, n = ndimage.label(mask)

out = np.zeros_like(mask, dtype=int)

for i in range(1, n+1):
    m = labels == i
    out[m] = mask[m].sum()
```

Output:

```
array([[12, 12, 12, 12,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [12, 12, 12, 12,  0,  7,  7,  0],
       [12, 12, 12, 12,  0,  7,  7,  7],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  7,  7],
       [ 0,  5,  5,  5,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  5,  5,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

it likes a data structure problem, you can use `deep first recursion` algroithm to do this.

```
def recursion(mask, h, w, i, j):
    if status[i][j]==True or mask[i][j]==0.0:
        return 
    status[i][j]=True
    if i-1>=0:
        recursion(mask, h, w, i-1, j)
    if j-1>=0:
        recursion(mask, h, w, i, j-1)
    if i+1<h:
        recursion(mask, h, w, i+1, j)
    if j+1<w:
        recursion(mask, h, w, i, j+1)

import numpy as np
mask = np.array([[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                     [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0],
                     [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
                     [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0],
                     [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                     [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]], dtype=np.float32)
status = np.zeros_like(mask, np.bool_)
ret = np.copy(mask)
h, w = mask.shape

for i in range(h):
    for j in range(w):
        if status[i][j]==False and mask[i][j]==1.0:
            recursion(mask, h, w, i, j)
            kk = np.sum(status)
            for ii in range(h):
                for jj in range(w):
                    if status[ii][jj]==True:
                        ret[ii][jj] = kk
                        status[ii][jj] = False
                        mask[ii][jj] = -1
ret
```